# React Item.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a name change handler for a value in state array personState.

```
const [personState, setPersonState] = useState([
            { id:'asdasd', name: "Max", age: 28 },
            { id:'asdasdsd', name: "Manu", age: 29 },
            { id:'assddasd', name: "Stan", age: 31 },
  ]);
```

Here's the function for handling name change event:

```
const nameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
        const personIndex = personState.findIndex(p => {
            return p.id === id;//find index of the value in personstate with id equal id passed in
        })
        const person = {...personState[personIndex]} // get all the object value inside that person

        person.name = event.target.value; //change name of that copy person to the input value

        const persons = [...personState]; //copy array of current personState
        persons[personIndex] = person// change value of that person in the array
        setPersonState(...personState, persons);//set state with the new array
    }
```

down below is where I use map to iterate through the personState array if the toggle show up. The mapping work for showing the data as well as deleting the data but when I want to implement name change, it suddenly return:

```
TypeError: personState.map is not a function
App
D:/React App/react-guide/src/App.js:52
  49 |  <button onClick={() => togglePersonHandler()}>
  50 |      Switch Name
  51 |  </button>
> 52 |  {showPerson ? personState.map((person,index) => {
  53 |       return <Person click = {()=>deletePersonHandler(index)} changed={(event) => nameChangeHandler(event, person.id)} key={person.id} name={person.name} age ={person.age}/>
  54 |     }) : null}
  55 | </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you need check what inside in `personState`. Try use console.log

Comment: Did you mean `setPersonState([...personState, persons])` instead of `setPersonState(...personState, persons)`?

Comment: You are not updating the state correctly and `nameChangeHandler` function is unnecessarily complicated. You can simplify the code in this function by using `map()` method to update the `personState` array.

Comment: [Here's how](https://pastebin.com/rrWBLcqx) you can simplify the `nameChangeHandler` function and update the state correctly.

Comment: Thank you guys the answer is written below.

Comment: @Yousaf Hi yousaf, I just saw the link you sent me. It was very helpful.
I was trying to follow a course and the inside that Person component I'm trying to pass down many functions to the children such as delete person handler, etc. So is it better to have map here or in the handler itself? Since I think it will save a bit of code if it's here because i don't have to declare map many times

Comment: _"So is it better to have map here or in the handler itself?"_ - not sure that you mean by _"here"_?

Comment: I meant in the JSX itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
setPersonState(...personState, persons);//set state with the new array
```

It should be replaced by the new value (only one parameter)

```
setPersonState(persons);//set state with the new array
```